# QML Update Json Model

Tags: json, qt, qml

I have an QT which gui is created in QML. I'm using a custom component which uses a model to display data. At runtime, this model will change. However the changes are not reflected.

```
MyCustomComponent
{
    property var myModel: [
        {
            icon: "qrc:/resources/my_icon1.png",
            data: "Initial text",
        },
        {
            icon: "qrc:/resources/my_icon2.png",
            data: "Initial text",
        }
    ]
    model: myModel

    property int myProp: 0

    onMyPropChanged:
    {
        refreshModel()
    }

    function refreshModel()
    {
        console.error("refreshModel: before: myModel:" + myModel[0].data +  ", model:" + model[0].data);
        myModel[0].data = "alternate text"
        console.error("refreshModel: after: myModel:" + myModel[0].data +  ", model:" + model[0].data);
    }
}
```

Outcome:

```
refreshModel: before: myModel:Initial text, model:Initial text
refreshModel: after: myModel:alternate text, model:Initial text
```

So at runtime `myProp` is changed, `refreshModel` will be called. However the `model` itself remains unchanged, the `myModel` does change.

Changing model directly and not does not work either. (so remove the myModel in-between property).

What do I need to do differently?

*Side note:*
Initially I was using a `ListModel` + `ListElement`, but this has other issues where I'm looking for an alternative `(ListElement: cannot use script for property value)`

Comment: If you implement your model in C++ (Using for example `QAbstractListModel`), changes in the model will be reflected to the ui. The reason this is not working here is that the simple list has no signals for changed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at what the Qt documentation says about the [`var` type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html).

> It is important to note that changes in regular properties of JavaScript objects assigned to a var property will not trigger updates of bindings that access them.

So in order for the update to be triggered, you have to manually emit the `myModelChanged` signal, just after you modify the model.

```
function refreshModel()
{
    console.error("refreshModel: before: myModel:" + myModel[0].data +  ", model:" + model[0].data);
    myModel[0].data = "alternate text"
    myModelChanged()
    console.error("refreshModel: after: myModel:" + myModel[0].data +  ", model:" + model[0].data);
}
```

Comment: That seems indeed do the trick. This only works when using an extra var property? You cannot directly change the model?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, modifying the myModel structure will not trigger a signal. I got used to this pattern, which has the advantage of using an immutable structure:

```
MyCustomComponent
{
    function computeModel(initial)
    {
        return [
            {
                icon: "qrc:/resources/my_icon1.png",
                data: initial ? "Initial text" : "alternate text",
            },
            {
                icon: "qrc:/resources/my_icon2.png",
                data: "Initial text",
            }
        ];
    }
    model: computeModel(true)

    property int myProp: 0

    onMyPropChanged:
    {
        model = computeModel(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: In short, you say you have to reassign model again.

Comment: Deleting and creating a model object to update a single field sounds really inefficient.

Comment: Yes, I can't remember if reassigning the same object will trigger the signal or not. Try immutability instead of premature optimisation.

Comment: The other way is to use `ListModel` with the `setProperty` or `set` function

Comment: @GrecKo Indeed but using ListModel it limits my usage. I want to be able to use defines in my model: "ListElement: cannot use script for property value"

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already point out, a JSON structure is a variant type. The *modelChanged* signal thus only fires in case you reassign a new value (new JSON) to the property. Doing small changes to parts of the structure will not fire the signal.

**Also Note:** When using such a variant model for e.g. your ListView, you will suffer from **performance and usability drawbacks** as well. Even if you modify the model and fire the signal manually, the view requires a full re-draw. It only knows that "*Something in the model changed*".

To avoid this, you can transform your JSON into an actual *ListModel* type (*QAbstractListModel* implementation), using *JsonListModel*:

```
MyCustomComponent
{
    property var myJson: [
        {
            id: 1,
            icon: "qrc:/resources/my_icon1.png",
            data: "Initial text",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            icon: "qrc:/resources/my_icon2.png",
            data: "Initial text",
        }
    ]

    model: JsonListModel {
      source: myJson
      keyField: "id"
    }

    property int myProp: 0

    onMyPropChanged:
    {
        refreshModel()
    }

    function refreshModel()
    {
        myJson[0].data = "alternate text"
        myJsonChanged() // emit changed signal, JsonListModel thus also updates
    }
}
```

You can find more details about the JsonListModel and its usage [here](https://v-play.net/apps/avoid-cpp-models-qt).